# How can I find subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ isomorphic to Klein four-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good night... I'm trying to find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ with excel, using $(a,b,c)$ and checking elements one by one and see if it is cyclic. Is there an easy way? How I can know how many subgroups are there? Is there a quick way to learn the generator of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$? How to determine if they are isomorphic to the Klein group? Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: The Klein group is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, so you have three choices by picking two out of the obvious $\mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: Using excel? How?

Comment: Sorry... Using excel Im able to find cyclic groups... With generator $(a,b)$

Answer (score 3):

Klein four group is given by presentation $\langle a,b\, |\, a^2 = b^2 = e\rangle$, thus all you need to do is find two elements of order $2$ inside $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_{12}$. Note that for $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_{12}$ $$2(a,b,c) = 0 \iff 2a = 2b = 2c = 0$$

so $a,b,c$ are of order $2$ or trivial. It follows that $(a,b,c)$ is of order $2$ if at least one of $a,b,c$ is of order $2$, and the rest are trivial. Thus, $a\in\{0,1\}$, $b\in\{0,2\}$, $c\in\{0,6\}$. This gives $2^3 - 1 = 7$ elements of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_{12}$ and since we need to pick two of them to get Klein group, there should be $\binom 7 2=21$ subgroups isomorphic to Klein four group, but every subgroup is counted three times that way: if we pick two elements $x,y$ of order $2$, then $$\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x, x+y\rangle = \langle y, x+y\rangle = \{ 0, x, y, x+y\}$$ so in fact there are only $7$ subgroups isomorphic to Klein four group.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! How can I get all groups? They are no cyclic then I cant check it by excel... With $n(a,b,c)$

Comment: @Salvattore, as I've writen, pick any two order $2$ elements, $\{0,a,b,a+b\}$ is Klein four group. You don't need excel to calculate $n(a,b,c)$ when $(a,b,c)$ is of order $2$.

Comment: then... I need to pick any two order 2 elements... $Z_2$ have one element order 2, it is ${1}$... $Z_4$ have one element ${2}$... And $Z_{12}$ have one element too ${6}$... Then I will pick any two order two elements $(1,2,0)$ and $(0,2,6)$... Then Klein four group could be ${(0,0,0),(1,2,0),(0,2,6),(1,0,6)}$... Am I ok??

Comment: @Salvattore, yes.

Comment: Thanks @Ennar, I understand it. I find all Klein group!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Klein four group is an abelian group but not cyclic
There is a subgroup Z2XZ2 is isomorphic to K4 but not to Z4 as it is cyclic